# How to choose indexing keys, should we consider keys from GROUPBY also with WHERE keys or just with WHERE keys?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Assume document sample schema

```
{
  "wherek1":"",
  "pk":""
  "groubby1":"",
  "groupby2":"",
  "count": 0
}
```

Assume select query

```
SELECT SUM(f.count) as outCount FROM TEST f WHERE f.pk='testk' and f.wherek1='hi' GROUP BY f.groubby1, f.groubby2
```

For the above query field should be indexed are

```
> pk/*
> wherek1/*
> groubby1/*
> groubby2/*
```

is my understanding correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding group by properties will not yield any benefit. Only those properties used in where, order by or join clauses see benefit being indexed.

One thing to keep in mind is that containers with high cardinality on properties used in group by can get expensive. If you plan on running queries like this frequently you may want to consider building a materialized view using Change Feed.

Some links that may be helpful.

[Queries with Group By](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#storing-datetimes)

[Lenni Lobel's blog on Change Feed](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2019/04/08/change-feed-unsung-hero-of-azure-cosmos-db/)

thanks.